# Android Studio - Erro ao tentar abrir projectos meus antigos

Tags: android, android-studio

Eu obtenho muitas vezes este erro ao tentar abrir alguns dos meus projectos antigos que ainda não pertencem ao Android Studio! Alguém sabe a solução para este problema? Obrigados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu Android SDK Manager:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: já tentou instalar o build tools 23.0.0.rc que ele mostra?

Comment: Olá Wellington. Eu editei a minha pergunta para acrescentar um imagem do meu atual Android SDK Manager. Eu penso que tenho instalado...?

Comment: Seus projetos também foram feitos no AndroidStudio ou por alguma outra IDE, como Eclipse?

Comment: Foram feitos numa anterior instalação do Android Studio. Tive de fazer uma instalação nova do Windows.